# Serverless Framework - AWS AppSync Arn reference error

Tags: serverless-framework, aws-appsync, serverless-appsync-plugin

Trying to create an IAM role for lambda to call AppSync API from the lambda function. But having trouble with referencing the Appsync resource.

The serverless.yml (truncated):

```
provider:
  iam:
    role:
      statements:
        - Effect: 'Allow'
          Action:
            - 'appsync:GraphQL'
          Resource: !Sub ${appsync:arn}/types/Mutation/fields/*
resources:
  Outputs:
    apiArn:
      Value: ${appsync:arn}
appSync:
  name: AppSync-api
  ...
```

Used the reference variable `${appsync:arn}` as mentioned in the [Serverless AppSync Plugin](https://github.com/sid88in/serverless-appsync-plugin#variables)
But running this giving me an error:

```
Cannot resolve serverless.yml: Variables resolution errored with:
  - Cannot resolve variable at "provider.iam.role.statements.6.Resource.Fn::Sub": String value consist of variable which resolve with non-string value
```

If I hardcode the arn with currently deployed API arn in Resource, I get the expected arn in Outputs after successful deployment. So, how can I dynamically reference the AppSync Api Arn in IAM role statement?

Answer (score 0):

It's a known limitation of Serverless AppSync plugin, it's described here:
https://github.com/sid88in/serverless-appsync-plugin/issues/569

As a workaround, you should be referring directly the CloudFormation resource, that plugin creates for you:

```
- Fn::Join: ["", [!GetAtt GraphQlApi.Arn, "/types/Mutation/fields/*"]]
```